# Is it possible to add charset in the body section?

Tags: javascript, html, perl, character-encoding

my website has the `<meta charset="utf-8">`tag. Now I want to integrate an old script which is written in perl and javascript, the problem is that this script is tagged with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">` and therefore it doesn't work in the `<meta charset="utf-8">` area.

I use `iframe` to integrate the script into my website. The script changes and analyses text and print this text in the `iframe` section, furthermore the script uses a parser which is based on `charset=windows-1252`.

Now my question: is it possible to add the `charset` attribute to the iframe tag or to add it to a div to generate an area in which only the `charset=windows-1252`is used?

Comment: I've solved the problem by using another `iframe` section with `src` on another side with the `charset=windows-1252` tag. But the question if its possible to use charset in the body part is still here